# Play Framework: creating new loggers

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm using Play Framework `2.3.8` and I'm trying to follow the documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaLogging)

So basically;

```
import play.api.Loggger

case class LoggedClass(someVal: String) {
    val logger = Logger("[LoggedClass]")
    def someFunc = logger.debug("Hello there!") // nothing in the log file
}
```

However, exactly this;

```
case class LoggedClass(someVal: String) {
    val logger = Logger
    def someFunc = logger.debug("Hello there!") // does all the logging
}
```

Is this a known bug? The documentation seems to say this should work but I see nothing in the o/p console of my IDE nor do I see anything in the log file.

Comment: Can you try to make the logger Name without `[]`?

Comment: @bjoernhaeuser doesn't help. I tried all kinds of strings.